# How do I check I know the password for an encrypted drive?

Tags: password, keychain, encryption

I've got an encrypted USB drive and I want to check I know the password. At the moment everything is in my keychain, so it works, and I can see its contents, but I want to make sure I'm covered if I need to replace my computer.

I want to make sure I can keep the contents if it turns out I've forgotten the password, so I don't want to delete any data from the keychain. (If I've forgotten the password, I'll need to copy its contents off before reformatting it.)

How do I do this?

Comment: Open KeyChain and look it up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in exporting all of the KeyChain in to Text file that you can save for later uses.

Be aware anyone with access to your computer can now plainly see that information.

Run this in Terminal

```
sudo security dump-keychain -d login.keychain > keychain.txt
```

You will have to click "Allow" till done, or use script that does that, but since it is usually one time action just do it manually.

Comment: Thanks - that was just the thing. The warning about everything being in plain text is noted - I have saved the dump to an encrypted volume, and carefully noted down the password hint for that. (The fact I didn't note down a password hint for my encrypted USB drive was what got me wondering about this whole problem in the first place.)

Comment: As you, I like  to keep all those passwords (including some seriously private like bank ect..) on a separate (USB) drive. Call me old fashion, I specifically do not like the online password programs, regardless how much they promise to be safe, as the history has shown, anything on the Internet/network can be hacked, but a USB stick that is in my drawer can not.